# Comparing date with exceptional date in asp.net Validator

Tags: html, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms

I am using compare validator of asp.net to compare the Date, I am comparing input date with today's date for that I have written code as below.

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="StartDateCompareVal" ValidationGroup="vgStep4" runat="server"
                                            ControlToValidate="txtDueDate" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Dateshould be greater than today's date."
                                            Operator="GreaterThan"  ValueToCompare="<%# DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() %>"
                                            Type="Date"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

It is working fine, but Now my requirement is that if someone enters date as 00/00/0000 so, No need to compare the value and should be accepted

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might want to use a `CustomValidator` instead of the `CompareValidator`.

.aspx page:

```
<form id="frmAspnet" runat="server">
    <asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" ID="vSummary" />
    <div>
        <label>
            Enter Date Greater Than Today:
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDate" />
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="cmdSubmit" Text="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

code behind:

```
private void cmdSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String validationGroup = "vgStep4";
    vSummary.ValidationGroup = validationGroup;
    Page.Validate(validationGroup);

    DateTime dateEntered = DateTime.TryParse(txtDate.Text, out dateEntered) ? dateEntered : DateTime.MinValue;
    Page.Validators.Add(new CustomValidator()
    {
        IsValid = (dateEntered > DateTime.Now.Date) || (txtDate.Text == "00/00/0000"),
        ValidationGroup = validationGroup,
        ErrorMessage = "Date should be greater than today's date."
    });

    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        // Date entered is valid!
        // or 00/00/0000 was entered
    }
}
```